# Vertically align different-sized logo images in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to vertically align all of my dummy logos like this via bootstrap:

However, for some reason vertical-align doesn't work and won't align my dummy logos at all.

here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container box">
                                <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4 client-logo-padding">
                                            <a href="" target="_blank" id="designmodo"></a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-4 client-logo-padding">
                                            <a href="" target="_blank" id="speckyboy"></a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-4 client-logo-padding">
                                                <a href="" target="_blank" id="pageresource"></a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-4 client-logo-padding">
                                                <a href="" target="_blank" id="firstwebdesigner"></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4 client-logo-padding">
                                                <a href="" target="_blank" id="codegeekz"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                        <div class="col-lg-4 client-logo-padding">
                                                <a href="" target="_blank" id="webdesignerdepot"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    
                            

                                    </div>
                            

</div>
```

You can check the whole codes here: https://jsfiddle.net/vknremso/

Any idea how can I attain this?

Comment: you can try flexbox or putting them in ul li and then apply the css accordingly.

Comment: Can you show me JSFIDDLE? I tried putting d-flex on the container or row did not work

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/atumqgsv/

Comment: "*d-flex on the container or row did not work*" That's because you need to do more than just add some classes - there are other problems in your code that are stopping the classes from working and need to be changed also. I've explained them in my answer below. Let me know if you need any more help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few changes you need to make to get this to work:

**1. You can use the Bootstrap classes** `align-items-center` to vertically centre the columns, and `text-center` to centre them horizontally:

```
<div class="row align-items-center text-center">
```

**2. Don't use a fixed `height` for the columns**, as this affects the Bootstrap flex layout that is doing the centring:

```
.client-logo-padding {
  /* height: 70px; */    /* <-- Remove this */
  padding-top:15px;      /* use padding to add space between the logos */
  padding-bottom:15px;
}
```

**3. You have an error in the `height` for the "designmodo" logo** - you have `height: 179px;` which is obviously going to affect the grid layout. I've changed that to `height: 27px;` - the actual height of the image.

**Working Example:** FYI I have changed the cols to `col-sm-4` to see the result in the snippet

```css
.client-logo-padding {
  padding-top:15px;  
  padding-bottom:15px;
}

.client-logo-padding a{
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  margin: 0px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#designmodo {
  width: 163px;
  height: 27px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/LtXWVvP.png');

}

#designmodo:hover {
  background-image: url('/assets/images/logo/designmodo-hover.png');
}

#firstwebdesigner {
  width: 94px;
  height: 48px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/zdtka18.png');
}

#firstwebdesigner:hover {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cufuXaU.png');
}

#codegeekz {
  width: 146px;
  height: 27px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/x13IZ8w.png');
}

#codegeekz:hover {
  background-image: url('/assets/images/logo/codegeekz-hover.png');
}

#webdesignerdepot {
  width: 94px;
  height: 48px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/spweqh2.png');
}

#webdesignerdepot:hover {
  background-image: url('/assets/images/logo/webdesignerdepot-hover.png');
}

#speckyboy {
  width: 152px;
  height: 35px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/7tI9oLb.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#speckyboy:hover {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/7tI9oLb.png');
}

#pageresource {
  width: 152px;
  height: 26px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/1AJZ9YD.png');

}

#pageresource:hover {
  background-image: url('/assets/images/logo/pageresource-hover.png');
}

.box {
  width: 600px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container box">
  <div class="row align-items-center text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4 client-logo-padding">
      <a href="" target="_blank" id="designmodo"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 client-logo-padding">
      <a href="" target="_blank" id="speckyboy"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 client-logo-padding">
      <a href="" target="_blank" id="pageresource"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 client-logo-padding">
      <a href="" target="_blank" id="firstwebdesigner"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 client-logo-padding">
      <a href="" target="_blank" id="codegeekz"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 client-logo-padding">
      <a href="" target="_blank" id="webdesignerdepot"></a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**Other Notes**

**You do not need to repeat the same CSS for each logo** - instead you can add the common CSS to a new rule- this makes it much easier to manage. e.g.

```
.client-logo-padding a{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    /* etc... */
}
```

**If the logo columns must have a height of 70px**, you can do it like this:

- delete the `.client-logo-padding` CSS rule
- remove the `height` from the CSS for all logos
- add the 70px height to the new `.client-logo-padding a` rule, and vertically centre the image in it:

```
    .client-logo-padding a{
        height: 70px;                 /* Set the height */
        background-position: center;  /* Vertically centre the image in the height */
        /* Rest of CSS... */
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="">Item-1</div>
    <div class="">Item-2</div>
    <div class="">Item-3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [answer].  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Also, this does not directly answer the question that was asked. Answers should show how to fix the specific problem that asked in the question and be applied to the code in the question.